# Currency convertor

Tags: python

I have an issue where the program wouldn't display the desired amount of amount  the user wanted to convert. Also how do you round the number to 3 decimal places, any ideas?

```
money = int(input("Enter the amount of money IN GDP you wish to convert :"))

USD = 1.25
EUR = 1.17
RUP = 83.87
PES = 25.68

currency = input("Which currency would you like to convert the money into?")

if currency == "USD":
    print(money) * USD
elif currency == "EUR":
    print(money) * EUR
elif currency == "RUP":
    print(money) * RUP
elif currency == "PES":
    print(money) * PES
```

Comment: This should help for rounding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: do **not** post pictures of code, post code as *formatted text* in the question itself.

Comment: "I have an issue where the program wouldn't display the desired amount of amount the user wanted to convert" - what is the issue?

Comment: I did not downvote you because I assumed this was a first question. Although, I should have but I didn't realize you've been on the site for a couple of months and you still do not post on-topic questions. Instead of whining about being downvoted, though, maybe you should strive *to post according to the guidelines*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Here is the error code after I state what currency I would lie it to convert to.      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amir\Downloads\CURRENCY CONVERTOR EXT.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (money) * 1.25
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: You should do `print( money * coef )` instead of `print( money ) * coef`

Comment: Please post error tracebacks *in the original question, not in the comments*.

Comment: @Reaper what is coef do I include it or substitute it with the currency

Comment: Do not use floats (or doubles) to represent money.  Use Decimal or integer number of cents.

Comment: @AmirBreakableTv Whatever you were multiplying `money` by.

Comment: @Reaper not working tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python includes the `round()` function which [lets you specify](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) the number of digits you want. So you can use `round(x, 3)` to do normal rounding up to 3 decimal places.

**Example**

```
print(round(5.368757575, 3)) # prints 5.369
```

**Update**

You can update your code in this way.

```
money = int(input("Enter the amount of money IN GDP you wish to convert: "))

USD = 1.25
EUR = 1.17
RUP = 83.87
PES = 25.68

currency = input("Which currency you like to convert the money into?: ")

if currency == "USD":
    print(round(money * USD, 3))
elif currency == "EUR":
    print(round(money * EUR, 3))
elif currency == "RUP":
    print(round(money * RUP, 3))
elif currency == "PES":
    print(round(money * PES, 3))
```

It outputs:

```
Enter the amount of money IN GDP you wish to convert: 100
Which currency you like to convert the money into?: USD
125.0

Enter the amount of money IN GDP you wish to convert: 70
Which currency you like to convert the money into?: RUP
5870.9
```

Comment: Do you know where I can implement this exactly in my code?